# Adding an edge between two unrelated vertices

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin

This question refers to Gremlin 3.0.2 (I'm bound to this since Titan has not advanced beyond 1.0.0 yet).

I'm trying to add an edge remotely between two vertices that have no (known) relation and whose Ids (i.e. "keys"?) are not known beforehand.
While in Gremlin 3.2 one would simply do

```
:> g.V().has('propertykey', 'value1').as('o').V().has('propertykey','value2').addE('edgelabel').to('o')
```

this keeps me stuck in Gremlin 3.0.2. What I tried so far (:

```
:> g.V().has('propertykey', 'value1').next().addOutE('edgelabel', g.V().has('propertykey', 'value2').next())
```

fails with the message

```
No signature of method: com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.CacheVertex.addOutE() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.CacheVertex, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [edgelabel, v[24776]]
```

The same error message will appear if one changes the second parameter of `addOutE` to `g.V(24776).next()`. Looking at the method signature of AddEdge it reveals that it expects a string for the key of the second vertex, but

```
> g.V().has('fbid', 'fbid_13').next().addOutE('edgelabel', '24776')
```

fails as well, stating that

```
No signature of method: com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.CacheVertex.addOutE() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [edgelabel, 24776]
```

So how one achieves this with Gremlin 3.0.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using TinkerPop v3.0.1 (bundled with Titan v1.0.0), you need to use the `withSideEffect` step.

```
:> g.withSideEffect('x', g.V().has('propertykey', 'value1')).V().has('propertykey', 'value2').addOutE('edgeLabel', 'x')
```

You're free to use any step label other than `x`.

Reference: [TinkerPop v3.0.1 AddEdge step](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#addedge-step)